# Assertion Error using a struct vector c++

Tags: c++, assertion

I have a program where I want to update a variable from a string. The function will read in a string, find if it is addition, subtraction, etc. and then add it to the variable. The function is this:

```
    using namespace std;

struct variable{
    string name;
    int value;
};

void update_varabile(string line, vector<variable> & v)
{
    char c = line[0];   //variable to be updated
    string b;
    char d[0];
    int flag = 0;       //counter
    int a = 0;
    int temp_value = 0;
    int perm_value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (c == v[i].name[0]) {
            flag = 1;
            temp_value = v[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {                //variable is present
        for (int i = 0; i< line.size(); i++) {
            if (line[i] == '+'|| line[i] =='-'|| line[i] == '*'|| line[i] =='/') {
                b[0] = line[i+1];               //assuming the integer is between 0 and 9
                d[0] = b[0];
                a = atoi (d);
            if (line [i] == '+') {
                perm_value = temp_value + a;
            } else if (line [i] == '-') {
                perm_value = temp_value - a;
            } else if (line [i] == '*') {
                perm_value = temp_value * a;
            } else if (line [i] == '/') {
                perm_value = temp_value / a;
            }
        }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v[i].name[0] == 'c') {
                v[i].value = perm_value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The call in main looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    variable a;
    int val = 0;
    string up = "c=c+2";
    string f = "c";
    vector<variable> q;
    a.name = f;
    a.value = val;
    q.push_back(a);
    update_varabile(up, q);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error message:

```
Assertion failed: ((m_->valid == LIFE_MUTEX) && (m_->busy > 0)), file C:/crossdev/src/winpthreads-git20141130/src/mutex.c, line 57

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 0.014 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I have run the debugger line by line and it shows that the function properly executes. I have also tried to look for that C:/ file on my computer and it doesn't exist. Not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, get rid of all the breaks. Only place breaks should be used in C++ is at the end of each case statement. Makes near impossible to read code with a bunch of breaks, because I have to go down and figure out what each break is there and why. If you need to get out of a for loop early, then use a while loop. you don't need breaks at the end of if and else statements because they cause the program to leave a function early, your if and else statements will naturally skip over if you are using if, else if, and else condition formatting.

Now having said that, you need to break down better what you are trying to do. 
example you get a string value like this. 
2+3+4-5+6
Your program is going to read from left to right. I am assuming you want it to take the first value which is two and then add three to it then four and so on and so fourth.

The way to do this is first parse the string for int values and then parse the addition and subtraction values. In other words read the int values out of the string untill you hit a value that is not between 0 and 9. Then see if that non-numerical value is an operator you are looking for. This way your program wont trip up on a value like 2555 and 2.

IE

```
//intValueHolder is a string.
while(i < line.size() && line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9' ) {
      intValueHolder.push_back(string[i]);
}
```

Then when you hit a '+' or something like that put the char value through a case statements. and don't forget to add a default value at the end to account for garbage input like 'a'. You may want to hold the value just incase you need to get your left side value first before you can get your right side value. But it sounded like you start out with a left side value so you really only need to find right and which operator it needs. I'm not going to rewrite your program because this looks like an assignment for school. But I will point you in the right direction. Let me know, if I was off on understanding your question.

You may also want to look into using queues for this, if you are not being restricted to just strings and vectors.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's for school, and I'm not looking for anyone to rewrite it; I am just trying to understand what is going on. We can assume that there will only be one integer being added, as I am testing this function for a bigger assignment. So, I don't have to worry about adding something like "34 + 56 - 9". It will only need to handle a simple statement like "c=c+2", which I think it will be able to do, according to the debugger. So, the format above will be the same for a statement like "c=c-3". If that points you in the right direction at all.

Comment: okay, so pretty much you are replacing c with the value in main?  Please clarify what the expected output should be with a certain input. So if you put in is "c=c-3" what would you expect to come back out? that way I can see where the error is happening. Also please drop the breaks, it's a bad programming habit to get into, I'm saying that from experience.

Comment: I got rid of them in my program, thanks for telling me. So, I've set val = 0 in main, and this program is going to read in that string that says "c=c+2", find that '+', and then know to add whatever comes after the + (in this case the number 2), then update the variable c. So, at the end, if I were to print out the value of c, it would be two. If the statement was "c=c-3", it would subtract 3 from 0, so -3 would be printed.

Comment: Then if you aren't worried about junk or other values. Just go through the string in till you run into a symbol, and then the rest of the string place in to another string and run atoi on it. Simple as that. Then run whatever you need to.